# How to configure multiple ssh keys based on repo owner

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I have two github accounts, one for work and one persona, both hosted in github.com without a subdomain. I would like to configure ~/.ssh/config based on repo owner for my work account all repos are under lets say `github.com/company_name/repo_name` and my projects are on `github.com/my_persona_user/repo_name`.

Thanks in advice for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+multiple+ssh+accounts

Comment: I saw that FAQ, but I wanted to avoid the use of the Host in the remote and be able to use the default clone url provided by github.

Answer (score 0):

Use your SSH config, as explained in the [Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusemultipleaccountswiththesamehostingproviderusingSSH):

```bash
# This is your work account
Host work
    HostName github.com
    User git
    # This is the key pair registered for your work account
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_work
    IdentitiesOnly yes
# This is the personnal account
Host perso
    HostName github.com
    User git
    # This is the key pair registered for your personal account
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_perso
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Then in your personal clones:

```
git remote set-url origin git@perso:my_persona_user/repo_name.git
```

and in work clones:

```
git remote set-url origin git@work:company_name/repo_name.git
```

Comment: I saw that FAQ, but I wanted to avoid the use of the Host in the remote and be able to use the default clone url provided by github.

Comment: OK, then maybe add that to your question since it makes it more precise :)